# The Cube Diorama demo file does not open

Tags: asset

I want a 3D representation of a room and would like to use Cube Diorama from Asset Bundles for this purpose. https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/
However, this file never wants to open. When I try to open this file, Blender crashes.

I have already tried opening this file via explorer and directly from Blender, but the file still won't open.

I have also reinstalled Blender and tried a different version.
Has anyone had this problem before, or know how to solve it?

Comment: Just downloaded and unzipped it. The Blend file opens fine here in both versions 3.5.1 and 3.6.1. I'd suggest you download the zip file again in case the download was corrupted.

Comment: @JohnEason, here it is still not opening...

Comment: Just to clarify: You downloaded the asset-demo-bundle-3.0-cube-diorama.zip file which should produce a 'cube_diorama' folder with a Blend file and a '.txt' file in it when you unzip it. You then added a path to that folder in Blender via Edit > Preferences > File Paths > Asset Libraries with the '+' sign beside it. You should then be able to go to the Assets Window in Blender and find the cube_diorama entry with all the objects and materials in it. If it's still crashing I can't really help any further.